# RSS feeds by category on multi blog version of BlogEngine: not working

Tags: url, rss, rss-reader, blogengine.net, blog-engine

I am using BlogEngine.NET, **Version: 3.3.0.0 / Configuration: Multiple blogs** on a site that I am maintaining. I am able to view and display feeds using a dynamic RSS feed reader within that structure: UNTIL I try to break it down by category. Example:

http://www.publicpartnerships.com/news/blog/syndication.axd

Works in the feed reader. Yet breaking the feed down by category:

***/news/blog/category/Client/syndication.axd***

Will not work. Also, here the feed reader that I've tweaked and purchased/have been using to display and test the feeds is here: http://cc.radykal.de/fancynews/

Is there a simple detail that I'm over-looking here that someone might be able to help me identify? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this. There is a feed within categories so it looks something like this:

http://www.publicpartnerships.com/news/blog/category/feed/Client

Thanks for hearing me out.